# Table design approach, what is the flaw?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a table like below:

tblQuestions    
---------------
ID(pk)  int
CustomerID(fk) int
QTypeID(fk) int
QNumber int
FieldName   varchar(max)
FieldValue  varchar(max)

clustered indexs on CustomerID, QTypeID, QNumber.
For each combination CustomerID, QTypeID and QNumber, there will be 4 to 5 records. 
and, for each customerID there would be at max 250 records.
Another way to design is to create 5 to 6 different tables with defined fields and customerid as foreign key with one record per customer.

My Question is, after how many records does the first approach starts to affect performance or would it ever?

Do you see anything wrong with this approach?  The maximum possible records might go up to 50 million records.

Comment: This is a very had question to answer without knowing what queries you expect to perform on the table. Can you share the DDL with us and some example queries?

Answer (score 1):

You may be prematurely optimizing here. Design your schema in the way that makes most sense in terms of normalization and removing duplication, not in terms of anticipated performance.

"My Question is, after how many records does the first approach starts to effect perfomance or would it ever?"

No one can answer this for you. If you want to know the perf characteristics of your proposed table design, mock it up, insert your 50M records and run some queries.

"Do you see any thing wrong with this approach?"

There's no right or wrong answers in database schema design. There are best practices like normalization, but there are plenty of reasons to de-normalize data too. Mock it up and test the perf if that's your concern.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. The reason I came up with fieldname field value is because the way I have a questionnaire, seems very complex to design in fully normalized form.